# How To Prevent Chrome From Stealing Focus When Opening A Tab In OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, chromium

If you open a new tab in Google Chrome on OSX, Chrome is automatically pulled into focus.  I'm working on automating some tasks and I want them to run in the background so I can do other things without Chrome jumping back into focus again.

The simplest way I can illustrate this issue is to open your JS console, paste this code:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.open('http://stackoverflow.com')}, 3000)
```

And quickly focus on a non-Chrome window.  Once the timeout completes, the new tab will be open (good) but also, the OS's focus will be brought back to Chrome (bad).

Is there a way to avoid this?  I was hoping to find a Chrome flag, setting in OSX, or similar.